# Consul Helm failing

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am trying to run consul in eks using helm. I ran below commands

helm repo add hashicorp https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com

kubectl create secret generic consul-gossip-encryption-key --from-literal=key=$(consul keygen) -n common

helm install consul hashicorp/consul --namespace common --set global.name=consul -f helm-consul-config.yaml --debug

It gives me below error

```
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: /root/.cache/helm/repository/consul-0.33.0.tgz

client.go:282: [debug] Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" ServiceAccount
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:282: [debug] Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" Role
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:282: [debug] Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" RoleBinding
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:282: [debug] Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" Job
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:491: [debug] Watching for changes to Job consul-tls-init with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:519: [debug] Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: ADDED
client.go:558: [debug] consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:519: [debug] Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
client.go:558: [debug] consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:519: [debug] Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
client.go:558: [debug] consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 1, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:519: [debug] Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
client.go:558: [debug] consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 2, jobs succeeded: 0
```

Upon checking pod logs I see below error

kubectl logs consul-tls-init-jqk8s -n common

/bin/sh: consul-k8s-control-plane: not found

Below is my helm config file

```
  enabled: true

  
  name: null

 
  domain: consul


  image: "consul:1.7.2"


  imagePullSecrets: []

 
  imageK8S: "hashicorp/consul-k8s:0.14.0"


  datacenter: dc1

  
  enablePodSecurityPolicies: false

 
  gossipEncryption:
    # secretName is the name of the Kubernetes secret that holds the gossip
    # encryption key. The secret must be in the same namespace that Consul is installed into.
    secretName: "consul-gossip-encryption-key"
    holds the gossip
    # encryption key.
    secretKey: "key"


  tls:
    enabled: true

  
    enableAutoEncrypt: true

    
    serverAdditionalDNSSANs: ["'consul.service.consul'"]

    
    serverAdditionalIPSANs: []

 
    verify: true

   
    httpsOnly: true

   
    caCert:
      secretName: null
      secretKey: null

    
    # certificates.
    caKey:
      secretName: null
      secretKey: null


  enableConsulNamespaces: false

  # [DEPRECATED] Use acls.manageSystemACLs instead.
  bootstrapACLs: false

  # Configure ACLs.
  acls:

    # If true, the Helm chart will automatically manage ACL tokens and policies
    # for all Consul and consul-k8s components. This requires Consul >= 1.4 and consul-k8s >= 0.14.0.
    manageSystemACLs: false

    # bootstrapToken references a Kubernetes secret containing the bootstrap token to use
    # for creating policies and tokens for all Consul and consul-k8s components.
    # If set, we will skip ACL bootstrapping of the servers and will only initialize
    # ACLs for the Consul and consul-k8s system components.
    # Requires consul-k8s >= 0.14.0
    bootstrapToken:
      secretName: null
      secretKey: null


    createReplicationToken: false

    
    replicationToken:
      secretName: null
      secretKey: null


server:
  enabled: "-"
  image: null
  replicas: 3
  bootstrapExpect: 3 # Should <= replicas count


  enterpriseLicense:
    secretName: null
    secretKey: null


  storage: 10Gi
  storageClass: null


  connect: true

 
  resources: null

  # updatePartition is used to control a careful rolling update of Consul
  # servers. This should be done particularly when changing the version
  # of Consul. Please refer to the documentation for more information.
  updatePartition: 0

  # disruptionBudget enables the creation of a PodDisruptionBudget to
  # prevent voluntary degrading of the Consul server cluster.
  disruptionBudget:
    enabled: true

    # maxUnavailable will default to (n/2)-1 where n is the number of
    # replicas. If you'd like a custom value, you can specify an override here.
    maxUnavailable: null

  # extraConfig is a raw string of extra configuration to set with the
  # server. This should be JSON.
  extraConfig: |
    {}


  extraVolumes: []
   

  # Affinity Settings
  # Commenting out or setting as empty the affinity variable, will allow
  # deployment to single node services such as Minikube
  affinity: |
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: {{ template "consul.name" . }}
              release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
              component: server
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname

  # Toleration Settings for server pods
  # This should be a multi-line string matching the Toleration array
  # in a PodSpec.
  tolerations: ""

  # nodeSelector labels for server pod assignment, formatted as a multi-line string.
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  # Example:
  nodeSelector: |
    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup: test
  priorityClassName: ""


  annotations: null

  service:
  
    annotations: null

 
  extraEnvironmentVars: {}
    # http_proxy: http://localhost:3128,
    # https_proxy: http://localhost:3128,
    # no_proxy: internal.domain.com


externalServers:
  
  enabled: false

 
  hosts: []

  # The HTTPS port of the Consul servers.
  httpsPort: 8501

  # tlsServerName is the server name to use as the SNI
  # host header when connecting with HTTPS.
  tlsServerName: null


  useSystemRoots: false


  k8sAuthMethodHost: null

# Client, when enabled, configures Consul clients to run on every node
# within the Kube cluster. The current deployment model follows a traditional
# DC where a single agent is deployed per node.
client:
  enabled: "-"
  image: null
  join: null

 
  dataDirectoryHostPath: null

  
  
  grpc: true

  
  exposeGossipPorts: false

  resources: null


  
  extraConfig: |
    {}

 
  extraVolumes: []
    by Consul

  
  tolerations: ""


  
  nodeSelector: null

  # Affinity Settings for Client pods, formatted as a multi-line YAML string.
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
  
  affinity: {}

  # used to assign priority to client pods
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/
  priorityClassName: ""

 
  annotations: null

 
  # custom consul parameters.
  extraEnvironmentVars: {}
    # http_proxy: http://localhost:3128,
    # https_proxy: http://localhost:3128,
    # no_proxy: internal.domain.com

  
  dnsPolicy: null

 
  updateStrategy: null

  snapshotAgent:
    enabled: false

    # replicas determines how many snapshot agent pods are created
    replicas: 2

 using-kubectl-create-secret
    configSecret:
      secretName: null
      secretKey: null


dns:
  enabled: "-"

 
  # Useful if you need to reference the DNS service's IP
  # address in CoreDNS config.
  clusterIP: null

  # Extra annotations to attach to the dns service
  # This should be a multi-line string of
  # annotations to apply to the dns Service
  annotations: null

ui:
  # True if you want to enable the Consul UI. The UI will run only
  # on the server nodes. This makes UI access via the service below (if
  # enabled) predictable rather than "any node" if you're running Consul
  # clients as well.
  enabled: "-"

  # True if you want to create a Service entry for the Consul UI.
  #
  # serviceType can be used to control the type of service created. For
  # example, setting this to "LoadBalancer" will create an external load
  # balancer (for supported K8S installations) to access the UI.
  service:
    enabled: true
    type: NodePort

    # Annotations to apply to the UI service.
    # Example:
    #   annotations: |
    #     "annotation-key": "annotation-value"
    annotations: null

    # Additional ServiceSpec values
    # This should be a multi-line string mapping directly to a Kubernetes
    # ServiceSpec object.
    additionalSpec: null

# syncCatalog will run the catalog sync process to sync K8S with Consul
# services. This can run bidirectional (default) or unidirectionally (Consul
# to K8S or K8S to Consul only).
#
# This process assumes that a Consul agent is available on the host IP.
# This is done automatically if clients are enabled. If clients are not
# enabled then set the node selection so that it chooses a node with a
# Consul agent.
syncCatalog:
  # True if you want to enable the catalog sync. Set to "-" to inherit from
  # global.enabled.
  enabled: false
  image: null
  default: true # true will sync by default, otherwise requires annotation

  # toConsul and toK8S control whether syncing is enabled to Consul or K8S
  # as a destination. If both of these are disabled, the sync will do nothing.
  toConsul: true
  toK8S: true

  # k8sPrefix is the service prefix to prepend to services before registering
  # with Kubernetes. For example "consul-" will register all services
  # prepended with "consul-". (Consul -> Kubernetes sync)
  k8sPrefix: null

  # k8sAllowNamespaces is a list of k8s namespaces to sync the k8s services from.
  # If a k8s namespace is not included  in this list or is listed in `k8sDenyNamespaces`,
  # services in that k8s namespace will not be synced even if they are explicitly
  # annotated. Use ["*"] to automatically allow all k8s namespaces.
  #
  # For example, ["namespace1", "namespace2"] will only allow services in the k8s
  # namespaces `namespace1` and `namespace2` to be synced and registered
  # with Consul. All other k8s namespaces will be ignored.
  #
  # To deny all namespaces, set this to [].
  #
  # Note: `k8sDenyNamespaces` takes precedence over values defined here.
  # Requires consul-k8s v0.12+
  k8sAllowNamespaces: ["*"]

  # k8sDenyNamespaces is a list of k8s namespaces that should not have their
  # services synced. This list takes precedence over `k8sAllowNamespaces`.
  # `*` is not supported because then nothing would be allowed to sync.
  # Requires consul-k8s v0.12+.
  #
  # For example, if `k8sAllowNamespaces` is `["*"]` and `k8sDenyNamespaces` is
  # `["namespace1", "namespace2"]`, then all k8s namespaces besides "namespace1"
  # and "namespace2" will be synced.
  k8sDenyNamespaces: ["kube-system", "kube-public"]

  # [DEPRECATED] Use k8sAllowNamespaces and k8sDenyNamespaces instead. For
  # backwards compatibility, if both this and the allow/deny lists are set,
  # the allow/deny lists will be ignored.
  # k8sSourceNamespace is the Kubernetes namespace to watch for service
  # changes and sync to Consul. If this is not set then it will default
  # to all namespaces.
  k8sSourceNamespace: null

  # [Enterprise Only] These settings manage the catalog sync's interaction with
  # Consul namespaces (requires consul-ent v1.7+ and consul-k8s v0.12+).
  # Also, `global.enableConsulNamespaces` must be true.
  consulNamespaces:
    # consulDestinationNamespace is the name of the Consul namespace to register all
    # k8s services into. If the Consul namespace does not already exist,
    # it will be created. This will be ignored if `mirroringK8S` is true.
    consulDestinationNamespace: "default"

    # mirroringK8S causes k8s services to be registered into a Consul namespace
    # of the same name as their k8s namespace, optionally prefixed if
    # `mirroringK8SPrefix` is set below. If the Consul namespace does not
    # already exist, it will be created. Turning this on overrides the
    # `consulDestinationNamespace` setting.
    # `addK8SNamespaceSuffix` may no longer be needed if enabling this option.
    mirroringK8S: false

    # If `mirroringK8S` is set to true, `mirroringK8SPrefix` allows each Consul namespace
    # to be given a prefix. For example, if `mirroringK8SPrefix` is set to "k8s-", a
    # service in the k8s `staging` namespace will be registered into the
    # `k8s-staging` Consul namespace.
    mirroringK8SPrefix: ""

  # addK8SNamespaceSuffix appends Kubernetes namespace suffix to
  # each service name synced to Consul, separated by a dash.
  # For example, for a service 'foo' in the default namespace,
  # the sync process will create a Consul service named 'foo-default'.
  # Set this flag to true to avoid registering services with the same name
  # but in different namespaces as instances for the same Consul service.
  # Namespace suffix is not added if 'annotationServiceName' is provided.
  addK8SNamespaceSuffix: true

  # consulPrefix is the service prefix which prepends itself
  # to Kubernetes services registered within Consul
  # For example, "k8s-" will register all services prepended with "k8s-".
  # (Kubernetes -> Consul sync)
  # consulPrefix is ignored when 'annotationServiceName' is provided.
  # NOTE: Updating this property to a non-null value for an existing installation will result in deregistering
  # of existing services in Consul and registering them with a new name.
  consulPrefix: null

  # k8sTag is an optional tag that is applied to all of the Kubernetes services
  # that are synced into Consul. If nothing is set, defaults to "k8s".
  # (Kubernetes -> Consul sync)
  k8sTag: null

  # syncClusterIPServices syncs services of the ClusterIP type, which may
  # or may not be broadly accessible depending on your Kubernetes cluster.
  # Set this to false to skip syncing ClusterIP services.
  syncClusterIPServices: true

  # nodePortSyncType configures the type of syncing that happens for NodePort
  # services. The valid options are: ExternalOnly, InternalOnly, ExternalFirst.
  # - ExternalOnly will only use a node's ExternalIP address for the sync
  # - InternalOnly use's the node's InternalIP address
  # - ExternalFirst will preferentially use the node's ExternalIP address, but
  #   if it doesn't exist, it will use the node's InternalIP address instead.
  nodePortSyncType: ExternalFirst

  # aclSyncToken refers to a Kubernetes secret that you have created that contains
  # an ACL token for your Consul cluster which allows the sync process the correct
  # permissions. This is only needed if ACLs are enabled on the Consul cluster.
  aclSyncToken:
    secretName: null
    secretKey: null

  # nodeSelector labels for syncCatalog pod assignment, formatted as a multi-line string.
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  # Example:
  # nodeSelector: |
  #   beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
  nodeSelector: null

  # Log verbosity level. One of "trace", "debug", "info", "warn", or "error".
  logLevel: info

  # Override the default interval to perform syncing operations creating Consul services.
  consulWriteInterval: null

# ConnectInject will enable the automatic Connect sidecar injector.
connectInject:
  # True if you want to enable connect injection. Set to "-" to inherit from
  # global.enabled.
  # Requires consul-k8s >= 0.10.1.
  enabled: false
  image: null # image for consul-k8s that contains the injector
  default: false # true will inject by default, otherwise requires annotation

  # The Docker image for Consul to use when performing Connect injection.
  # Defaults to global.image.
  imageConsul: null

  # The Docker image for envoy to use as the proxy sidecar when performing
  # Connect injection. If using Consul 1.7+, the envoy version must be 1.13+.
  # If not set, the image used depends on the consul-k8s version. For
  # consul-k8s 0.12.0 the default is envoyproxy/envoy-alpine:v1.13.0.
  imageEnvoy: null

  # namespaceSelector is the selector for restricting the webhook to only
  # specific namespaces. This should be set to a multiline string.
  # See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#matching-requests-namespaceselector
  # for more details.
  # Example:
  # namespaceSelector: |
  #   matchLabels:
  #     namespace-label: label-value
  namespaceSelector: null

  # k8sAllowNamespaces is a list of k8s namespaces to allow Connect sidecar
  # injection in. If a k8s namespace is not included or is listed in `k8sDenyNamespaces`,
  # pods in that k8s namespace will not be injected even if they are explicitly
  # annotated. Use ["*"] to automatically allow all k8s namespaces.
  #
  # For example, ["namespace1", "namespace2"] will only allow pods in the k8s
  # namespaces `namespace1` and `namespace2` to have Connect sidecars injected
  # and registered with Consul. All other k8s namespaces will be ignored.
  #
  # To deny all namespaces, set this to [].
  #
  # Note: `k8sDenyNamespaces` takes precedence over values defined here and
  # `namespaceSelector` takes precedence over both since it is applied first.
  # `kube-system` and `kube-public` are never injected, even if included here.
  # Requires consul-k8s v0.12+
  k8sAllowNamespaces: ["*"]

  # k8sDenyNamespaces is a list of k8s namespaces that should not allow Connect
  # sidecar injection. This list takes precedence over `k8sAllowNamespaces`.
  # `*` is not supported because then nothing would be allowed to be injected.
  #
  # For example, if `k8sAllowNamespaces` is `["*"]` and k8sDenyNamespaces is
  # `["namespace1", "namespace2"]`, then all k8s namespaces besides "namespace1"
  # and "namespace2" will be available for injection.
  #
  # Note: `namespaceSelector` takes precedence over this since it is applied first.
  # `kube-system` and `kube-public` are never injected.
  # Requires consul-k8s v0.12+.
  k8sDenyNamespaces: []

  # [Enterprise Only] These settings manage the connect injector's interaction with
  # Consul namespaces (requires consul-ent v1.7+ and consul-k8s v0.12+).
  # Also, `global.enableConsulNamespaces` must be true.
  consulNamespaces:
    # consulDestinationNamespace is the name of the Consul namespace to register all
    # k8s pods into. If the Consul namespace does not already exist,
    # it will be created. This will be ignored if `mirroringK8S` is true.
    consulDestinationNamespace: "default"

    # mirroringK8S causes k8s pods to be registered into a Consul namespace
    # of the same name as their k8s namespace, optionally prefixed if
    # `mirroringK8SPrefix` is set below. If the Consul namespace does not
    # already exist, it will be created. Turning this on overrides the
    # `consulDestinationNamespace` setting.
    mirroringK8S: false

    # If `mirroringK8S` is set to true, `mirroringK8SPrefix` allows each Consul namespace
    # to be given a prefix. For example, if `mirroringK8SPrefix` is set to "k8s-", a
    # pod in the k8s `staging` namespace will be registered into the
    # `k8s-staging` Consul namespace.
    mirroringK8SPrefix: ""

  # The certs section configures how the webhook TLS certs are configured.
  # These are the TLS certs for the Kube apiserver communicating to the
  # webhook. By default, the injector will generate and manage its own certs,
  # but this requires the ability for the injector to update its own
  # MutatingWebhookConfiguration. In a production environment, custom certs
  # should probably be used. Configure the values below to enable this.
  certs:
    # secretName is the name of the secret that has the TLS certificate and
    # private key to serve the injector webhook. If this is null, then the
    # injector will default to its automatic management mode that will assign
    # a service account to the injector to generate its own certificates.
    secretName: null

    # caBundle is a base64-encoded PEM-encoded certificate bundle for the
    # CA that signed the TLS certificate that the webhook serves. This must
    # be set if secretName is non-null.
    caBundle: ""

    # certName and keyName are the names of the files within the secret for
    # the TLS cert and private key, respectively. These have reasonable
    # defaults but can be customized if necessary.
    certName: tls.crt
    keyName: tls.key

  # nodeSelector labels for connectInject pod assignment, formatted as a multi-line string.
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  # Example:
  # nodeSelector: |
  #   beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
  nodeSelector: null

  # aclBindingRuleSelector accepts a query that defines which Service Accounts
  # can authenticate to Consul and receive an ACL token during Connect injection.
  # The default setting, i.e. serviceaccount.name!=default, prevents the
  # 'default' Service Account from logging in.
  # If set to an empty string all service accounts can log in.
  # This only has effect if ACLs are enabled.
  #
  # See https://www.consul.io/docs/acl/acl-auth-methods.html#binding-rules
  # and https://www.consul.io/docs/acl/auth-methods/kubernetes.html#trusted-identity-attributes
  # for more details.
  # Requires Consul >= v1.5 and consul-k8s >= v0.8.0.
  aclBindingRuleSelector: "serviceaccount.name!=default"

  # If you are not using global.acls.manageSystemACLs and instead manually setting up an
  # auth method for Connect inject, set this to the name of your auth method.
  overrideAuthMethodName: ""

  # aclInjectToken refers to a Kubernetes secret that you have created that contains
  # an ACL token for your Consul cluster which allows the Connect injector the correct
  # permissions. This is only needed if Consul namespaces [Enterprise only] and ACLs
  # are enabled on the Consul cluster and you are not setting
  # `global.acls.manageSystemACLs` to `true`.
  # This token needs to have `operator = "write"` privileges to be able to
  # create Consul namespaces.
  aclInjectToken:
    secretName: null
    secretKey: null

  # Requires Consul >= v1.5 and consul-k8s >= v0.8.1.
  centralConfig:
    # enabled controls whether central config is enabled on all servers and clients.
    # See https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#enable_central_service_config.
    # If changing this after installation, servers and clients must be restarted
    # for the change to take effect.
    enabled: true

    # defaultProtocol allows you to specify a convenience default protocol if
    # most of your services are of the same protocol type. The individual annotation
    # on any given pod will override this value.
    # Valid values are "http", "http2", "grpc" and "tcp".
    defaultProtocol: null

    # proxyDefaults is a raw json string that will be written as the value of
    # the "config" key of the global proxy-defaults config entry.
    # See: https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/config-entries/proxy-defaults.html
    # NOTE: Changes to this value after the chart is first installed have *no*
    # effect. In order to change the proxy-defaults config after installation,
    # you must use the Consul API.
    proxyDefaults: |
      {}

# Mesh Gateways enable Consul Connect to work across Consul datacenters.
meshGateway:
  # If mesh gateways are enabled, a Deployment will be created that runs
  # gateways and Consul Connect will be configured to use gateways.
  # See https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/mesh_gateway.html
  # Requirements: consul >= 1.6.0 and consul-k8s >= 0.9.0 if using
  # global.acls.manageSystemACLs.
  enabled: false

  # Globally configure which mode the gateway should run in.
  # Can be set to either "remote", "local", "none" or empty string or null.
  # See https://consul.io/docs/connect/mesh_gateway.html#modes-of-operation for
  # a description of each mode.
  # If set to anything other than "" or null, connectInject.centralConfig.enabled
  # should be set to true so that the global config will actually be used.
  # If set to the empty string, no global default will be set and the gateway mode
  # will need to be set individually for each service.
  globalMode: local

  # Number of replicas for the Deployment.
  replicas: 2

  # What gets registered as WAN address for the gateway.
  wanAddress:
    # source configures where to retrieve the WAN address (and possibly port)
    # for the mesh gateway from.
    # Can be set to either: Service, NodeIP, NodeName or Static.
    #
    # Service - Determine the address based on the service type.
    #   If service.type=LoadBalancer use the external IP or hostname of
    #   the service. Use the port set by service.port.
    #   If service.type=NodePort use the Node IP. The port will be set to
    #   service.nodePort so service.nodePort cannot be null.
    #   If service.type=ClusterIP use the ClusterIP. The port will be set to
    #   service.port.
    #   service.type=ExternalName is not supported.
    # NodeIP - The node IP as provided by the Kubernetes downward API.
    # NodeName - The name of the node as provided by the Kubernetes downward
    #   API. This is useful if the node names are DNS entries that
    #   are routable from other datacenters.
    # Static - Use the address hardcoded in meshGateway.wanAddress.static.
    source: "Service"

    # Port that gets registered for WAN traffic.
    # If source is set to "Service" then this setting will have no effect.
    # See the documentation for source as to which port will be used in that
    # case.
    port: 443

    # If source is set to "Static" then this value will be used as the WAN
    # address of the mesh gateways. This is useful if you've configured a
    # DNS entry to point to your mesh gateways.
    static: ""

  # The service option configures the Service that fronts the Gateway Deployment.
  service:
    # Whether to create a Service or not.
    enabled: true

    # Type of service, ex. LoadBalancer, ClusterIP.
    type: LoadBalancer

    # Port that the service will be exposed on.
    # The targetPort will be set to meshGateway.containerPort.
    port: 443

    # Optionally hardcode the nodePort of the service if using type: NodePort.
    # If not set and using type: NodePort, Kubernetes will automatically assign
    # a port.
    nodePort: null

    # Annotations to apply to the mesh gateway service.
    # Example:
    #   annotations: |
    #     "annotation-key": "annotation-value"
    annotations: null

    # Optional YAML string that will be appended to the Service spec.
    additionalSpec: null

  # Envoy image to use. For Consul v1.7+, Envoy version 1.13+ is required.
  imageEnvoy: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.13.0

  # If set to true, gateway Pods will run on the host network.
  hostNetwork: true

  # dnsPolicy to use.
  dnsPolicy: null

  # Override the default 'mesh-gateway' service name registered in Consul.
  # Cannot be used if global.acls.manageSystemACLs is true since the ACL token
  # generated is only for the name 'mesh-gateway'.
  consulServiceName: ""

  # Port that the gateway will run on inside the container.
  containerPort: 8443

  # Optional hostPort for the gateway to be exposed on.
  # This can be used with wanAddress.port and wanAddress.useNodeIP
  # to expose the gateways directly from the node.
  # If hostNetwork is true, this must be null or set to the same port as
  # containerPort.
  # NOTE: Cannot set to 8500 or 8502 because those are reserved for the Consul
  # agent.
  hostPort: null

  # If there are no connect-enabled services running, then the gateway
  # will fail health checks. You may disable health checks as a temporary
  # workaround.
  enableHealthChecks: true

  resources: |
    requests:
      memory: "128Mi"
      cpu: "250m"
    limits:
      memory: "256Mi"
      cpu: "500m"

  # By default, we set an anti affinity so that two gateway pods won't be
  # on the same node. NOTE: Gateways require that Consul client agents are
  # also running on the nodes alongside each gateway Pod.
  affinity: |
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: {{ template "consul.name" . }}
              release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
              component: mesh-gateway
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname

  # Optional YAML string to specify tolerations.
  tolerations: null

  # Optional YAML string to specify a nodeSelector config.
  nodeSelector: null

  # Optional priorityClassName.
  priorityClassName: ""

  # Annotations to apply to the mesh gateway deployment.
  # Example:
  #   annotations: |
  #     "annotation-key": "annotation-value"
  annotations: null

# Control whether a test Pod manifest is generated when running helm template.
# When using helm install, the test Pod is not submitted to the cluster so this
# is only useful when running helm template.
tests:
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Helm chart that is compatible with the version of Consul you are installing. The last supported Helm chart version which is compatible with Consul 1.7.2 is [version 0.21.0](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/hashicorp/consul/0.21.0). See the compatibility matrix for Consul and Consul on Kubernetes at https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/upgrade/compatibility for more info.

You should be able to successfully install Consul by using the following Helm install command.

```
$ helm install consul hashicorp/consul --version 0.21.0 --namespace common --set global.name=consul -f helm-consul-config.yaml
```

Follow the instructions at https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/upgrade if you wish to upgrade to a newer version of Consul.